# How to test launching new Activity with Espresso via OnClick action?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, android-testing

I have a `RecyclerView` in my Fragment and by clicking on each item an activity (`SampleActivity`) have to launch.

I wrote some UI test for this behavior like this:

```
 @Test
    public void listRecyclerView_ClickOnTapligh() {

        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(simpleListFragment.idlingResource);

        onView(withId(R.id.root_list))
          .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(1, click()));

        Intents.init();
        intended(hasComponent(SampleActivity.class.getName()));
        Intents.release();
    }
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: has component: has component with: class name: is "com.sample.sdk.android.view.SamppleActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String
```

I also tried this

```
intended(hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), TaplighActivity.class)));
```

But I had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:

```
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<SampleActivity> activityRule 
        = new ActivityTestRule<>(SampleActivity.class, true, false);   

    @Test
    public void listRecyclerView_ClickOnTapligh() {
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(simpleListFragment.idlingResource);
        onView(withId(R.id.root_list))
          .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(1, click()));

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("some_key", "some_value");
        activityRule.launchActivity(intent);
    }
```